# include a directory path in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory-structure

In my .htaccess file

```
php_value auto_append_file "run_me_first.php"
```

Because I want to run it first before any other file. Now it works if `run_me_first.php` and `foo.php` are in the same directory but once I do something like going in a directory, it gives me this error `(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')`

```
root
|_ .htaccess
|_ run_me_first.php
|_ foo.php
|_ folder1
   |_ bar.php // If I try to access this, give me the error above.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the **full path** linking to your root folder, to make your rule directory-recursive. You can see the path on your cPanel, or using php function [`getcwd()`](https://www.php.net/getcwd) in `run_me_first.php`.

In my case the path would be like this:

```
php_value auto_append_file "/home/userID/public_html/run_me_first.php"
```

Note: If you want to prepend file(in this case your appending the file to the end of every file), use `auto_prepend_file` instead.

Comment: How can I append the string? Gives me 500 error. I do something I this `php_value auto_prepend_file %{getcwd()} run_me_first.php` How can I achieve something like this `getcwd() . "run_me_first.php"`

Comment: No, echo `getcwd()` in your `run_me_first.php` file, and then get value from there. Then paste it to your .htaccess file.

Comment: Ahh I see. So there is no way of doing it more like a dynamic string. Thanks.

Comment: No I don't think so. But the path is always the same, so you don't have to use the function more than once.